# Prepared statement echo JSON encode turns empty result

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

```
if(isset($_POST["id"])){  
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM account WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST["id"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->get_result();
    
    echo json_encode($row);
}
```

For some reason, the result is empty and produces this error.
Trying to access array offset on value of type null

What am I doing wrong? nothing I find seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `$stmt->get_result();` just gets the result from the `mysqli_stmt` object into a `mysqli_result` object, you still have to fetch result rows as a separate call

```
if(isset($_POST["id"])){  
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM account WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST["id"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    
    //You still need some version of a FETCH after $stmt->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    echo json_encode($row);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. small edit, $row = $result->fetch_assoc() needs to be $row = $result->fetch_assoc();